# Where have I gone wrong with this complicated equation?

Tags: integration

The formula on the card is:

> $$
> \frac {4}{pi}, \int_0^\infty \frac {\sin\left ( \frac {\left (\ln\sum_{n=0}^\inf  \frac {x^n}{n!}\right)^2}{\ln \log_{n\to\infty} \left (1+\frac xn\right)^n}\right)}{\frac {101x}{\sum_{i=0}^{100}i}}\,dx.
> $$

I have:

$$\ (\ln(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}))^2 = x^2$$

and

$$\sum_{i=2}^{100} i = 5049$$

However I do not know what the log with base $n$-infinity means. I assume it means the limit, in which case I find the limit is
$\ e^x $, however I could be wrong.

I can't work out the answer.

Comment: I agree that $\log_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ probably means $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$

Answer (score 1):

It has to be the limit; there is no given meaning to $\log_{n\to\infty}$. With $\log$ replaced with $\lim$, you have
\begin{align}
\frac4\pi\,\int_0^\infty\frac {\sin\left ( \frac {\left (\ln\sum_{n=0}^\inf  \frac {x^n}{n!}\right)^2}{\ln \lim_{n\to\infty} \left (1+\frac xn\right)^n}\right)}{\frac {101x}{\sum_{i=0}^{100}i}}\,dx
&=
\frac{4\times5049}{101\pi}\,\int_0^\infty\frac {\sin x}{x}\,dx\\ \ \\
 &=
\frac{200}{\pi}\,\frac\pi2=100.\\ \ \\
\end{align}